# Custom build 64 bit kernel do not run 32 bit apps

Tags: kernel

I build a custom kernel ,64 bit for a tablet asus t100 .
Using this custom kernel everthing works very good ,wifi bluetooth etc , but my ubuntu x64 do nit run 32 bit apps .
I think it must be the kernel because when i boot default ubuntu kernel the 32 bit apps works .
Is there a specific kernel configure option that I have to enable so my custom kernel to run 32 bit apps?
Thank you

Comment: Did you install `libc6:i386`?

Comment: Yes everything is installed ,when i boot default ubuntu kernel apps works ,but when i boot my custom kernel they say invalid elf file

Comment: If you list the modules for each kernel when running (lsmod |sort ), do you see any differences?

Comment: i   see default kernel use this and my custom do not use : syscopyarea , sysfillrect , sysimgbit wtch are related to drm_kms_helper witch i think is from video card  and , tpm_crb

Comment: The exact error is : can not execute binary file : Exec format error . All other 64 bit apps works very well and this kernel is good cause it have all drivers . Only problem is with the 32 bit apps not running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that you've left out a kernel configuration option to enable support for 32-bit binaries. Do you have `CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION` defined in your custom kernel?

If not, enable it through the `make menuconfig` interface, and rebuild.

Comment: yes CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION was not used , and google did not helped to find out .Thank you!